# Trying to show list items vertically but two items horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a list with emails in a `<ul>` element:

- email 1
- email 2
- email 3
- email 4

And I want to show this list items in vertical like I write before, but I also want my email 1 and email 2 in horizontal like:

- email 1 / email 2
- email 3
- email 4

I already try use a class with display:inline but dont work!

Somebody there already did something like this and know how I can do it?

I have this html:

```
<footer id="footer-container">
    <section id="footer1"> 
       <div id="col">
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="email"><a href="#">email 1</a></li>
                <li class="email"><a href="#">email 2</a></li>
                <li class="email"><a href="#">email 3</a></li>
                <li class="email"><a href="#">email 4</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>  
   </section>
</footer>
```

And this Css:

```
     #footer-container
{
    width:100%;
    float:left; 
    background:brown;   
}

#footer1
{
    width:480px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}


#footer1 ul 
{
 /*list-style:none*/
}

#footer1 ul li
{
    margin:0 0 7px 0;
}

#footer1 ul li a 
{   
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:15px;
}

#col
{
    float:left;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    width:480px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJSLZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `nth-child(-n+2)` to change the display of the first two elements to `inline-block`.

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GrG2/)

```
li.email:nth-child(-n+2) {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

..and if you want the bullet points, alternative [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ7j2/).

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't simply change the HTML to put email 1 and email 2 in the same `<li>`?

Example:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">email 1</a> / <a href="#">email 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">email 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">email 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">email 5</a></li>
</ul>
```